# Как сделать так, чтобы код выполнялся после завершения таймера (setTimeout), а не сразу?

Tags: javascript

Создал функцию, в середине кода которой - setTimeout. При выводе получается, что выполняется начальный и конечный код, и только после этого, когда проходит таймер выполняется тот, что в середине, как сделать так, чтобы код выполнялся в хронологическом порядке?

Comment: Либо использовать последовательность, либо промисы. Покажите, пожалуйста, Ваш код - тогда сможем помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предположить по вашим словам , что вам нужно это.

```js
console.log('Код выше');
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('Код в setTimeout');
  console.log('Код который "в конце"')
}, 10000)
```